# `use` package scope: how to make it cross files?

Tags: perl

In `scriptA.pl`, there is `use DBI`

In `scriptB.pl`, there is `require "scriptA.pl"`

But we still cannot use DBI package in `scriptB.pl`

Any way to handle this except repeating  `use DBI` in `scriptB.pl`?

Comment: What is the symptom that makes you say you cannot use DBI package in scriptB.pl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scoped nature of [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) is a documented feature:

> #### **`use Module`**
>
> Imports some semantics into the current package from the named module, generally by aliasing certain subroutine or variable names into your package.

You could do what you want by going back to the stone age as in the following example, but please don't.

Using `MyModule` as a stand-in for `DBI`:

```
package MyModule;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw/ foo /;
sub foo { print "$_[0]!\n" }

1;
```

and then calling `MyModule::foo` from `scriptA.pl`

```
foo "from scriptA";
```

and from `scriptB.pl`

```
foo "from scriptB";
```

all kicked off from a main program of

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use MyModule;

do "scriptA.pl" or die;
do "scriptB.pl" or die;

print "done.\n";
```

gives the following output:

```
from scriptA!
from scriptB!
done.
```

You also could disable the scoping safety-feature with nasty `eval` games, but please don't do that either.

If your design needs improvement—maybe `scriptA` and `scriptB` belong in the same package—that would be a far better investment of your time. Otherwise, bite the bullet and expend nine keystrokes.

Please note that executing Perl libraries at runtime via `do` or `require` are a seriously dated approaches. The [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) documentation describes the modern approach.

Answer (score 8):

There are ways, but they are all more ugly, hacky and unclean than simply typing `use DBI;` in every file that uses it.  This is the best practice and is quite normal.

Answer (score 2):

I find myself wondering what it is you are attempting to achieve?

If you simply want to reduce boilerplate code (15 common `use Foo` declarations in every file), you can use a module like [ToolKit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ToolSet-1.00/lib/ToolSet.pod) to create a standard set of modules to use:

Put this into Powerboy.pm:

```
 package Powerboy;

 use base 'ToolSet'; 

 ToolSet->use_pragma( 'strict' );
 ToolSet->use_pragma( 'warnings' );

 ToolSet->export(
     'DBI'  => undef,  # Export the default set of symbols
 );

 1;
```

And then in your scripts, simply do:

```
 use Powerboy;

 # We have strict, warnings and DBI now.
```